# Найти строки в которых значение столбцов совпадают linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть таблица, в которой n столбцов.
Нужно используя linq найти одинаковые строки по определенным столбцам.

[image: Вот входные даные]

Нужно получить те строки, в которых совпадают значения столбцов.

Пытался сделать так:

```
var _MistakeAll = from a in ire.TimeTable
                  from b in ire.TimeTable
                  where (a.id != b.id)
                     && (a.id_auditori != null
                      && b.id_auditori != null
                      && a.den != null
                      && a.para != null
                      && b.den != null
                      && b.para != null)
                     && a.den == b.den
                     && a.para == b.para
                     && (a.nedelya > 2
                      || b.nedelya > 2
                      || a.nedelya == b.nedelya)
                     && (a.id_auditori == b.id_auditori
                      || a.id_teacher == b.id_teacher)
                  select a;
```

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных и пример ожидаемого результата

Comment: дабы не портить глаза разглядыванием закорючек на мониторе, хорошо бы фрагмент проблемного кода оформлять в виде компилируемого и исполняемого кода. Это резко увеличит количество людей, готовых поучаствовать в решении Вашей проблем, ИМХО

Comment: Во всех ячейках находятся цифры. Мне скинуть пример заполненной таблицы?

Comment: @Vivus, пример входных данных (с цифрами и буквами) и то что должно быть не выходе. Ну и напишите что не устраивает в вашем варианте

Comment: Если я правильно понял.)

Answer (score 1):

Для группировки данных по определенному значению мы можем использовать метод [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Value1, x.Value2 })
```

Перечисляем все те столбцы, которые нас интересуют

---

Пример

Класс

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public int Value4 { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Value1} | {Value2} | {Value3} | {Value4}";
    }
}
```

Метод для генерации тестовых данных

```
static IEnumerable<SomeClass> getData(int count)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return
        Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(_ => new SomeClass
        {
            Value1 = rand.Next(3),
            Value2 = rand.Next(3),
            Value3 = rand.Next(3),
            Value4 = rand.Next(3)
        });
}
```

Тест

```
int count = 10;
var data = getData(count).ToList();
data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
var group = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Value1, x.Value2 });
foreach(var subgroup in group)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"KEY = {subgroup.Key}");
    foreach (var value in subgroup)
        Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Результат

```
1 | 2 | 2 | 1
1 | 2 | 1 | 1
0 | 2 | 2 | 1
1 | 2 | 2 | 2
1 | 0 | 2 | 2
0 | 2 | 0 | 2
1 | 1 | 2 | 1
2 | 2 | 2 | 0
2 | 0 | 2 | 2
1 | 1 | 2 | 2
KEY = { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2 }
1 | 2 | 2 | 1
1 | 2 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 2 | 2
KEY = { Value1 = 0, Value2 = 2 }
0 | 2 | 2 | 1
0 | 2 | 0 | 2
KEY = { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 0 }
1 | 0 | 2 | 2
KEY = { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 1 }
1 | 1 | 2 | 1
1 | 1 | 2 | 2
KEY = { Value1 = 2, Value2 = 2 }
2 | 2 | 2 | 0
KEY = { Value1 = 2, Value2 = 0 }
2 | 0 | 2 | 2
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я пытаюсь это сделать используя только linq. Если использовать foreach, обработка идет очень долго.

Comment: Как в одной таблице найти одинаковые строки используя linq?

Comment: @Vivus Linq медленный, если не хватает скорости - переносите отбор на БД. `foreach` это просто обход элементов.

Comment: @Vivus тут принято каждый отдельный вопрос оформлять отдельно. Также существует система чатов, где можно обсудить проблемы. Например, [C#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--) комната или [общий](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) чат

Comment: Понял! Спасибо!